# How to calculate longitudinal force on two rods where each is fixed at one end to the ground and connected to each other at the other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

Imagine a 2D scenario.

There are 2 rods.

Both are fixed at one end to the ground (some distance away from each other).  The connections to the ground are universal joints that are free to rotate.

The rods are connected to each other at the other end (forming a pyramid).  The connection point is also a zero-friction joint.

The rods are not necessarily the same length.  Now a force $F$ is applied at an arbitrary vector to where the rods are connected.

Nothing moves because everything is connected.

What are the longitudinal forces on the rods?

I am thinking about building a 3DOF robot whose 3 arms are actuators.  I would like to learn to do this kind of calculation to better understand the loads I can expect to place on the arms.